# Reuse variable after cutting string

Tags: batch-file, window

This is my first steps in windows batching and I've a question,

If I added this to script file:

```
IF %p_monitorName%=="workflow_failed" (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ("%p_monitorStatus: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%c in ("%%b by =.%") do echo %%c >> %scriptdir%\..\logs\SIS2OVOOutput.txt
)
```

It works but if i tried to use %%c anywhere else in script it failed, do you've any suggestions ?

Comment: You should show what you have tried that is failing, and describe the result you want.

Comment: If you need the value in the `for` replaceable parameter out of the `for` command, save it into a variable `set "value=%%c"`

Comment: @MCND : This is not working

Comment: @dbenham  simply, I've did the above then I tried to echo %%c outside if condition but didn't work, I removed the IF condition and I tried to echo After for loop directly but it didn't work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Variables of the form `%%c` are only valid within a FOR loop context. They are undefined or inaccessible outside of a FOR loop. If you must access the value outside the loop, then transfer the value to an environment variable or CALL argument from within the loop.

FOR variables are global across all FOR loops. Normally you cannot access FOR variables from within a subroutine that was CALLed from within the loop. But you can gain access by instantiating a new FOR loop.

Using normal `%A%` expansion within a loop (within any parentheses block) cannot access a new value that was set within the same block. Delayed expansion `!A!` should be used instead. Delayed expansion must be enabled via `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "A=Old Value"
for /f "delims=" %%A in ("Loop Value") do (
  echo Value within loop: %%A
  set "A=%%A"
  echo Value of %%A%% within loop: %A%
  echo Value of ^^!A^^! within loop: !A!
  call :sub "%%A"
)
for %%X in (dummy) do echo Value within X loop after A loop over: %%A
echo Value of %%A%% persists: %A%
exit /b

:sub
echo Value outside of loop: %%A
echo value of %%A%%: %A%
echo Value of %%A%% within subroutine: %A%
echo Value of ^^!A^^! within subroutine: !A!
echo value of %%~1: %~1
for %%X in (dummy) do echo Value within X loop while in subroutine: %%A
exit /b
```

--OUTPUT--

```
Value within loop: Loop Value
Value of Loop Value% within loop: Old Value
Value of !A! within loop: Loop Value
Value outside of loop: %A
value of %A%: Loop Value
Value of %A% within subroutine: Loop Value
Value of !A! within subroutine: Loop Value
value of %~1: Loop Value
Value within X loop while in subroutine: Loop Value
Value within X loop after A loop over: %A
Value of %A% persists: Loop Value
```